# Scrapy How to scrape items from multiple pages?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data of # pages. I have already done a scraper which can scrape data from a single # page. But it suddenly finished the work after scraping of the first page

The whole file with parse function and scrapd function - Scraper.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import csv
import os
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Request

class Proddduct(scrapy.Item):
    price = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    content = scrapy.Field()


class LapadaScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lapada_scraper2'
    allowed_domains = ['http://www.lapada.org']
    start_urls = ['https://lapada.org/art-and-antiques/?search=antique']

    def parse(self, response):
        next_page_url = response.xpath("//ul/li[@class='next']//a/@href").get()

        for item in self.scrape(response):
            yield item

        if next_page_url:
            print("Found url: {}".format(next_page_url))
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def scrape(self, response):
        parser = scrapy.Selector(response)

        products = parser.xpath("//div[@class='content']")

        for product in products:
            item = Proddduct()
            XPATH_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION  = ".//strong/text()"
            XPATH_PRODUCT_PRICE  = ".//div[@class='price']/text()"
            XPATH_PRODUCT_LINK = ".//a/@href"

            raw_product_description = product.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION).extract()
            raw_product_price = product.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_PRICE).extract()
            raw_product_link = product.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_LINK).extract_first()

            item['description'] = raw_product_description
            item['price'] = raw_product_price
            item['link'] = raw_product_link

            yield item

    def get_information(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item'] 
        item['phonenumber'] = "12345"
        yield item
```

How can I scrape all items in all pages?

Thanks

Comment: Does ```self.parse``` gets called the second time at all?

Comment: @NikolayShindarov, no. It executes only once and then finishes the work.

Comment: What’s the value you get for `nextpageurl`?

Comment: In this case, what is the printed output value of ```nextpage``` just before you send it as a parameter to ```scrapy.Request```?

Comment: @Gallaecio - nextpage: https://lapada.org/art-and-antiques/?search=antique&pg=2

Comment: @NikolayShindarov answered below.

Comment: With or without https:// ?

Comment: @NikolayShindarov with.

Comment: If `nextpageurl` is not None, then a request is sent. The logs should indicate whether it is crawled or ignored (e.g. invalid response status code, duplicate request URL)

Comment: @Gallaecio  I provide you with the output after `print("Found url: {}".format(nextpage))` 
I got
 `Found url: https://lapada.org/art-and-antiques/?search=antique&pg=2
2019-11-07 16:25:59 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-11-07 16:25:59 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 560,...`

Comment: Please, provide your whole spider and try to remove unneeded code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), let’s see if we can reproduce it locally.

Comment: @Gallaecio I provided the code

Comment: From my logs running your spider: `2019-11-07 18:23:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'lapada.org': <GET https://lapada.org/art-and-antiques/?search=antique&pg=2>`

Answer (score 2):

Change `allowed_domains = ['http://www.lapada.org']` to `allowed_domains = ['lapada.org']`

Comment: also I am trying to visit following link of product with the previous code and part `request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_information)` but I got error `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`. Can you help me with it please?

Comment: Please, try to find help in the Internet first, and if you cannot find any, open a separate question following https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. That way, if what is happening to you happens to someone else in the future, it will be much easier for them to find your question and whatever good answer you get.